# Es6 global variable not available in class

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, babeljs, jsdom

i try to make my `window` variable available in my imported class. In the imported class it says, that window is not defined.

I use mocha and chai to test my javascript code. Also babeljs for the es6 part.

This is my test.js:

```
import { jsdom } from 'jsdom';
import { assert } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import Pixels from './../src/pixels.es6';

let document, window, pixels;

describe('Pixels', () => {

    beforeEach(function () {
        let el;

        document = jsdom('<html><body></body></html>');
        window = document.defaultView;

        el = document.createElement('div');
        el.setAttribute('data-flow-id', Date.now());
        pixels = new Pixels(el);
    });

    describe('spawn()', function () {

        beforeEach(function () {
            window.dataLayer = {
                push: sinon.spy()
            };

            pixels.spawn();
        });

        afterEach(function () {
            window.dataLayer = {};
        });

        it('should push to dataLayer', function () {
            assert.isTrue(window.dataLayer.push.called);
        });

    });

});
```

And this is the imported class where `window` is not available:

```
import { URL } from './config.es6';
import Parse from './parse.es6';
import fetch from 'safe-fetch';

export default class Pixels {
    constructor (el) {
        console.log(window);
        this.el = el;
        this.fetch = fetch || window.fetch;
    }

    spawn () {
        this.fetch(URL, {
            reportChildRequestId: false,
            method: 'get'
        }).then(resp => {
            return resp.text();
        }).then(html => {
            // ... do stuff with html variable
        });
    }
}
```

The mocha call is: `mocha --require babel-core/register`.

Is there a way to make the `window` variable available in `Pixels`, besides passing it in the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [mocha-jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-jsdom) npm package. With this package i don't need to create `window` and `document` because it will do this for me and all is working as expected.

Updated code:

```
import { jsdom } from 'mocha-jsdom';
import { assert } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import Pixels from './../src/pixels.es6';

let pixels;

describe('Pixels', () => {

    jsdom();

    beforeEach(function () {
        let el;

        el = document.createElement('div');
        el.setAttribute('data-flow-id', Date.now());
        pixels = new Pixels(el);
    });

    describe('spawn()', function () {

        beforeEach(function () {
            window.dataLayer = {
                push: sinon.spy()
            };

            pixels.spawn();
        });

        afterEach(function () {
            window.dataLayer = {};
        });

        it('should push to dataLayer', function () {
            assert.isTrue(window.dataLayer.push.called);
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is weird behavior. 
The only thing I can think of is maybe this is a behavioral scope issue with let? I know that it has slightly different scope authority, but I would think since it is in the global scope of things, that this wouldn't be an issue. Did you try, just to see, using `var document, window, pixels;` instead of `let  document, window, pixels;`? Other than that, I don't see an issue. I hope this can be of some help. Let me know if you figure it out, I'm actually quite curious, thanks!

Comment: The `var` was not the problem. So, the same undefined window object like with `let`.

Comment: @danbruegge It was worth a try :D . Glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason it should work. Your `window` variable in `test.js` is declared in the top scope of that file. *This is not global.* Furthermore, `jsdom` does not pollute the global space. So you cannot count on it for creating a global `window`.

You might be able to get something working by assigning to `global.window`, but I would not do this. If you want to test code that is meant to run in the browser, **you should have `jsdom` load it**. This means passing a real HTML page to it that references your script.

Comment: What do you mean by "you should have jsdom load it" ?

Comment: After a bit of research, i found mocha-jsdom and its doing what i want to accomplish. :) https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-jsdom